# Python ImportError: How to resolve "No module named main" in Google appengine project?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have setup a google appengine project in my ubuntu system for the first time and made everything works till now by reading all the documentation available online. But here I have stuck, it is running properly on localhost using command:`dev_appserver.py app.yaml` but when I try to access my app on my browser, it throws the error: `ImportError: No module named main`

> Project Structure

```
-GAE_Demo
-google_appengine
-src
 -handlers.py
 -main.py
-app.yaml
-config.json
```

> app.yaml

```
url: /.*
script: main.app
secure: always
```

> src/main.py

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(
routes=([('/main', MainHandler)]),
debug=True)
```

> Error

```
INFO     2017-10-17 01:32:58,464 module.py:821] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
ERROR    2017-10-17 01:56:21,976 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/path/to/project/GAE_Demo/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/path/to/project/GAE_Demo/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/path/to/project/GAE_Demo/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
ImportError: No module named main
```

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 1):

First, going off-script on your first App Engine project (by putting `.py` files in `src/`, which none of the tutorials I know of do), is setting you up for frustrations that are better avoided until you have a successful project under your belt.

The easy way forward is to move the files in `src/` up a level. But if you really, really want to stick with `src/`, then try adding an `__init__.py` to `src/`, and change your `app.yaml` to

```
url: /.*
    script: src.main.app
    secure: always
```